# Spring 3 -- form with 2 buttons, sending 2 parameters to controller method

Tags: spring-mvc, submit, http-status-code-404, parameter-passing

I have a Spring 3 MVC form with 2 parameters I'm trying to send to my controller method, and I'm getting a 404 error.  The twist on this problem is that the form has 2 submit buttons, and the submit button that is clicked dictates the value of one of the parameters.  Here is my form.

```
    <form:form action="/approve/${bulletin.id}" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><b>From:</b> <c:out value="${bulletin.name}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><b>Subject:</b> <c:out
                        value="${bulletin.subject}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><b>Date:</b> <c:out value="${bulletin.date}" />
                    <br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><t:notePrint note="${bulletin.note}" /> <input
                    type="hidden" name="id" value="${bulletin.id}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="approve" value="Approve" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="deny" value="Deny" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
    </form:form>
```

Here is my controller form.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/approve/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String approveBulletin(@RequestParam int id,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "approve") String approve,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "deny") String deny, Model model) {
    try {
        if (approve.equalsIgnoreCase("approve")) {
            bulletinDAO.approveBulletin(id);
            model.addAttribute("approval",
                    "Your bulletin has been approved.");
        }
        if (deny.equalsIgnoreCase("deny")) {
            bulletinDAO.denyBulletin(id);
            model.addAttribute("approval", "Your bulletin has been denied.");
        }

        List<Bulletin> bulletins = bulletinDAO.getApprovedBulletins();
        model.addAttribute("bulletins", bulletins);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return "FailurePage";
    }

    return "ApproveBulletin";
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have solved my own problem.  I am posting my code for the benefit of anyone else who hits this thread with the same problem.  Here is my form.

```
<form:form action="approve" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><b>From:</b> <c:out value="${bulletin.name}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><b>Subject:</b> <c:out
                    value="${bulletin.subject}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><b>Date:</b> <c:out value="${bulletin.date}" />
                <br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><t:notePrint note="${bulletin.note}" /> <input
                type="hidden" name="id" value="${bulletin.id}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="approve" value="Approve" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="deny" value="Deny" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
</form:form>
```

Here are my controller methods.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/approve", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "approve" })
public String approve(@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam String approve, Model model) {
    try {
        bulletinDAO.approveBulletin(id);
        model.addAttribute("approval", "Your bulletin has been approved.");

        List<Bulletin> bulletins = bulletinDAO.getApprovedBulletins();
        model.addAttribute("bulletins", bulletins);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return "FailurePage";
    }

    return "ApproveBulletin";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/approve", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "deny" })
public String deny(@RequestParam int id, @RequestParam String deny, Model model) {
    try {
        bulletinDAO.denyBulletin(id);
        model.addAttribute("approval", "Your bulletin has been denied.");

        List<Bulletin> bulletins = bulletinDAO.getApprovedBulletins();
        model.addAttribute("bulletins", bulletins);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return "FailurePage";
    }

    return "ApproveBulletin";
}
```

Comment: And how it is possible to test this with MockMVC ?

Comment: This was not tested with MockMVC.  This was tested using the application in Tomcat as a user would normally use it.

Answer (score 10):

Your form's `action` is set to **"/approve"** yet your Controller mapping is **"/approve/{action}/{id}"**; the Dispatcher Servlet has no way of making the connection between these two.

Even if the method *was* mapped correctly it wouldn't do what you expect it to do: you're confusing `action` and `input` and what they correspond to in the HTTP request.

`action` sets the URL of the form request, in your case it's "**/approve**".
Each `<input>` element's `name` parameter is used to add HTTP parameters with value of `value`, so the request would have a combination of:

- `id=${id}` (all requests)
- `approve=Approve` (if user clicked "approve")
- `deny=Deny` (if user clicked "deny")

To handle both these cases the controller's signature should be changed to something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/approve", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String approveBulletin(@RequestParam int id,
            @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="") String approve,
            @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="") String deny,
            Model model) {
    if (approve.equals("Approve")) {
      // user clicked "approve"
    } else if (deny.equals("Deny")) {
      // user clicked "deny"            
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Need either approve or deny!");
    }

    // (...)
}
```

But I'd rather suggest changing the parameters of the submit buttons:

```
<td><input type="submit" name="approveParam" value="approveVal" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="approveParam" value="denyVal" /></td>
```

This way you always get exactly two parameters: `id` and `approve`, then you can just check the value of `approve` to see if it was an "approve" or a "deny":

```
public String approveBulletin(@RequestParam int id,
        @RequestParam(value = "approveParam") String approveOrDeny,
        Model model) {
    if (approveOrDeny.equalsIgnoreCase("approveVal")) {
        // user clicked "approve"
    } else if (approveOrDeny.equalsIgnoreCase("denyVal")) {
        // user clicked "deny"
    } else {
        // wrong parameter sent
    }
```

---

What helps diagnosing such problems (ie. whether it's the client or server problem) is inspecting the outgoing request using browser's web tools (Firebugs in Firefox, Developer Tools in Chrome, etc.). You can easily capture the request and see what the HTTP parameters, URL and method were and compare them to your expectations.

Comment: I've updated my original post with the latest version of my code, per your suggestions.  The id is now being passed, but not the value of the button I clicked.

Comment: Can you confirm whether you can see the "approve" or "deny" parameter in the request? (using your browser tools) I've just tested that on a simplified form, it sends the button's value correctly.

Comment: I just found the parameter in Firebug.  Under Net / All / Post, I'm seeing this: id=%25%7Bid%7D&approve=Approve.  How should I rewrite the code?

Comment: The approve/deny part should be handled correctly, you'll have to change "%{id}" in your JSP to "${id}" to replace this placeholder with actual integer ID. Updated my answer to include a code example of the other suggested option.

Comment: I've done what you suggested, but I'm still getting a 404 error.  In Firebug, under Net / All / Post, I notice in the Parameters section, it's listing approve before id, but I'm wondering if it's just listing them in alphabetical order.  In the Source section, it's still giving me the same garbage as above, id=%25%7Bid%7D&approve=Approve.  I'm guessing it's putting curly braces around the string "id" instead of the actual id (an int) without any curly braces.  Any id on how to correct this?  The garbage string has the parameters in the correct order.

Comment: What is the @RequestMapping that you have given at the class level? And what is the url you use to get your form page?

Comment: I've solved the garbage that's being sent to the controller by changing the hidden field to ${bulletin.id}.  In answer to Vinay's question, I notice that the URL from the calling page is localhost:8080/jcbulboard/waitingBulletins, but the URL I get the 404 on is localhost:8080/approve, without the jcbulboard.