# How to send String value back to Spring MVC?

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc, hidden-field

### Problem

My view has two forms:

```jsp
<form:form method="post" action="/insertChapter" modelAttribute="Chapter">
<form:input type="hidden" path="chapter" value="${info.chapter}"/>
<form:input path="title" />
<input type="submit" value="Insert" />
</form:form>

<form:form method ="GET" action="/deleteChapter" modelAttribute="What is here?">
<form:hidden path = "chapter" value ="${info.chapter}"/>
<input type="submit" value="Delete Chapter ${info.chapter}" />
</form:form>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/insertChapter")
public String insertChapter(@ModelAttribute Chapter chapter) {
    if (chapter != null)
        infoService.insertChapter(chapter.getChapter(), chapter.getChapter());
        return "redirect:/getInfoListList";
}
@RequestMapping("/deleteChapter")
public String deleteChapter(@RequestParam String chapter) {
    infoService.deleteChapter(chapter);
    return "redirect:/getInfoListList";
}
```

but the server complained:

> An exception occurred processing JSP page .. in line 62

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'chapter' available as request attribute
```

and then

> Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command'
>   available as request attribute

### Question / Answers

So what is the correct way to set the value of a hidden field?  My controller needs to know the value and the value is not constant because I have different values in different forms.

Anything I need to do for the Chapter to be automatically delivered to the controller?

And when to use form:input and when to use just input?  I see sometimes the examples online just use `<input ...>` instead of `<form:input>`

### Answer:

It seems that I should use ModelAttribute in the controller which generates the first page (in addition to the one for processing the post).

### Additional Questions

Then it comes with a second question, how to let the controller handle a String ModelAttribute, and how to set let Chapter and String be handled?  Is the following function sufficient?

```
@RequestMapping("/getInfoListList")
public ModelAndView getInfoListList(@ModelAttribute Chapter chapter, @ModelAttribute String chaptertobedeleted) {
    List<List<Info>> infoList = infoService.getInfoListList();
    ModelAndView aModel =new ModelAndView("infoListList", "infoListList", infoList);
    return aModel;
}
```

Comment: There should be much more to it than that. Where do you see that error?

Comment: thank you for pointing out.  The error says  Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'Chapter' available as request attribute.  I guess I will look into that

Comment: Yes, there are multiple questions/answers regarding that issue. You simply haven't provided a request/model attribute named `Chapter` in _this_ request.

Comment: I updated with the controller showing the ModelAttribute Chapter.  Chapter has {String chapter, String title} as java fields.

Comment: Note how I wrote _You simply haven't provided a request/model attribute named Chapter in **this** request._ **this** being the request that renders the JSP, not the request that handles the form submission.

Comment: I see what you mean now. So the contoller that contains the form (using return ModeAndVew) should have ModelAttribute Chapter chaper as well?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't have to be through `@ModelAttribute`, you can simply add the attribute to the `Model` with `model.addAttribute("chapter", new Chapter())`. It's up to you.

Comment: So where should I declare model?

Comment: It can be a method parameter `Model model`. You should be able to add the attribute to the `ModelAndView` as well.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, why don't you put these as an answer?  I checked and found it is working.

Comment: I've written this answer down so many times, as others have. I was hoping you'd delete your question once I explained what the problem was.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, thanks.  One more questioni added as the new problem is exposed after the first problem is solved.

Comment: You wouldn't use a `@ModelAttribute` for a `String`, just a `@RequestParam`. I recommend deleting this question and asking a new one, providing all the details necessary to answer.

Comment: What if I wanted to post another type (not String,not Chapter)?

Comment: Depends on the type. Depends on how you post it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, could you write the code for both jsp form and the handler function? It's a form get but I stll don't know how to deliver a sting vaue back.

Comment: There are tons of examples out there. Take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514501/spring-3-form-with-2-buttons-sending-2-parameters-to-controller-method) for example. Search on Stack Overflow or elsewhere. Spring is extremely well documented.

Comment: I followed that link and it worked.  However, why my original jsp using <form:input type = "hidden" path = "chaptertobedeleted" vaue = ...> doesn't work?

Comment: What doesn't work? What error do you get? If you're trying to retrieve a single `<input>` parameter value in your controller, you should check your HTML and see what the `name` of the `<input>` is. That's the name you need to use in `@RequestParam`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I moved to question [25715891](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715891/whats-the-correct-way-to-write-a-form-for-spring-mvc-with-forminput) and I will delete this quesiton soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple questions.

What is the commandName specified in the controller.
is it `info` and does `info` has `chapter` attribute.

try using this if `info` is the `commandName`

```
<form:form method="post" action="/insertChapter" commandName="info">
```

Comment: Chapter has String chapter, title so is this a bad idea that the field is same with the type except case.

Comment: info is from another ModelView.  Another jsp not shown here uses info to generate the values in ModelAttribute Chapter in the form to be delivered to /insertChapter.