# What's the correct way to write a form for Spring MVC with form:input

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc

### Goal

I want to write a form in Spring MVC and use form:input consistently

```jsp
<form:form method="post" action="/insertChapter" modelAttribute="Chapter">
<form:input type="hidden" path="chapter" value="${info.chapter}"/>
<form:input path="title" />
<form:input type="submit" value="Insert" />
</form:form>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/insertChapter")
public String insertChapter(@ModelAttribute Chapter chapter) {
    if (chapter != null)
        infoService.insertChapter(chapter.getChapter(), chapter.getChapter());
        return "redirect:/getInfoListList";
}
```

but the server complained:

> infoListList.jsp (line: 83, column: 7) According to the TLD or the tag file, attribute path is mandatory for tag input

line 83 is the one with form:input type = "submit"...

### Question

So what is the correct way to write this jsp form?  I know how to write with form without form:input. 
What is the difference between form:input and just input?  Is it considered a good style to mix form:input and just input (for submit button)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot use "form:input"  tag to submit form.
To submit the form you should use "form:button" tag
or else you can use html "input" tag with type="submit".

```
<body>
<form:form modelAttribute="pizza" action="add" method="POST">

    Pizza name:<form:input path="name" />
    <br>
    <br>
    Pizza price:<form:input path="price" />
    <br>
    <br>
    Select Base<form:select id="baseList" path="base" items="${baseList}"
        itemLabel="name" itemValue="baseId"></form:select>
    <br>
    <br>
    Select Toppings
    <form:checkboxes items="${toppingList}" itemLabel="name"
        itemValue="toppingId" path="toppings" />

    <form:button>Submit</form:button>
</form:form>
```

Comment: Can you write a complete example using the <form:button>?